# Which Passport version is compatible with Laravel 5.7.15, default installation does not work

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

As a part of Laravel 5.7 setup, I am trying to install Passport using the command:

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

But it doesn't work and gives the error:

```
Using version ^8.0 for laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - laravel/passport 8.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0].
    - laravel/passport v8.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0].
    - laravel/passport v8.0.1 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0].
    - laravel/passport v8.0.2 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.7.15].
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - don't install illuminate/support 7.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.15, required as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.15].
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

It looks like the Passport version 8.0 is not compatible with the Version 5.7.15 of Laravel, which version is compatible here?

Answer (score 14):

I have simply chosen the older version of Passport: v7.5.1

```
composer require laravel/passport  "7.5.1"
```

and the installation worked successfully:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 15 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.23): Loading from cache
  - Installing defuse/php-encryption (v2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/event (2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/oauth2-server (7.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing firebase/php-jwt (v5.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/passport (v7.5.1): Downloading (100%)         
symfony/psr-http-message-bridge suggests installing nyholm/psr7 (For a super lightweight PSR-7/17 implementation)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-libsodium (SSH2/SFTP can make use of some algorithms provided by the libsodium-php extension.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-mcrypt (Install the Mcrypt extension in order to speed up a few other cryptographic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/passport
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Passport 10.* requires Laravel 8.*.

https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/UPGRADE.md